# Supporting Multiple Python Versions In Your Code?

Tags: python, versioning

Today I tried using [pyPdf](http://pybrary.net/pyPdf/) 1.12 in a script I was writing that targets Python 2.6. When running my script, and even importing pyPdf, I get complaints about deprecated functionality (md5->hashsum, sets). I'd like to contribute a patch to make this work cleanly in 2.6, but I imagine the author does not want to break compatibility for older versions (2.5 and earlier).

Searching Google and Stack Overflow have so far turned up nothing. I feel like I have seen try/except blocks around import statements before that accomplish something similar, but can't find any examples. Is there a generally accepted best practice for supporting multiple Python versions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

---

(1) Just like you described: Try something and work around the exception for old versions. For example, you could try to import the `json` module and import a userland implementation if this fails:

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import myutils.myjson as json
```

This is an example from Django (they use this technique often):

```
try:
    reversed
except NameError:
    from django.utils.itercompat import reversed     # Python 2.3 fallback
```

If the iterator `reversed` is available, they use it. Otherwise, they import their own implementation from the `utils` package.

---

(2) Explicitely compare the version of the Python interpreter:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 6, 0):
    # Do stuff for old version...
else:
    # Do 2.6+ stuff
```

`sys.version_info` is a tuple that can easily be compared with similar version tuples.

Answer (score 4):

You can certainly do

```
try:
  import v26
except ImportError:
  import v25
```

[Dive Into Python—Using Exceptions for Other Purposes](http://www.diveintopython.net/file_handling/index.html#d0e14344)

Comment: +1, but here's a direct link to the relevant section: http://diveintopython.org/file_handling/index.html#d0e14344

Answer (score 0):

Multiple versions of Python *are* supported here. You can a) conditionally use the newer version, which takes a little work, or b) turn off the warnings, which should really be the default (and is on newer Pythons).